# Could sleep(1) called in thread cause crash?

Tags: ios

I have used the HUD in my project. This situation will occur in my application: in main thread it will do a animation, and in the subthread it will call sleep.
I would receive the crash log like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x383d55b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x36b7b822 -[UIAnimator stopAnimation:] + 262
2   UIKit                           0x36c16252 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 290
3   UIKit                           0x36b7b384 -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 48
4   QuartzCore                      0x35c7006c CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch(unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 156
5   QuartzCore                      0x35c6ffc4 CA::Display::IOMFBDisplayLink::callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 60
6   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x312a6fd4 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 152
7   IOKit                           0x312ab446 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 190
8   CoreFoundation                  0x3646d5d8 __CFMachPortPerform + 116
9   CoreFoundation                  0x36478170 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
10  CoreFoundation                  0x36478112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
11  CoreFoundation                  0x36476f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
12  CoreFoundation                  0x363e9eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
13  CoreFoundation                  0x363e9d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
14  GraphicsServices                0x385962e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
15  UIKit                           0x36a622fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
16  YH_EMenu                        0x000e36c4 main (main.m:14)
17  YH_EMenu                        0x000dd6cc start + 36

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38503d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a278a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x384f3648 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33cc8974 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33cc8654 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 32

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x384f2eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x384f3048 mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36478040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36476d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878
4   CoreFoundation                  0x363e9eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x363e9d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x385f9a70 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a3230e _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a321d4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38503d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a278a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38503d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a27a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a278a0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385036a4 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a373ce nanosleep + 138
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a97de6 sleep + 42
3   YH_EMenu                        0x000eb580 -[MainViewController threadENDSHOWHUD:] (MainViewController.m:939)
4   Foundation                      0x342ae678 __NSThread__main__ + 968
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a3230e _pthread_start + 306
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33a321d4 thread_start + 4
```

I have no idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: An EXC_BAD_ACCESS error typically indicates a memory problem - trying to make use of memory which has been deallocated, for example. It's unlikely the thread sleeping is causing that, and the log indicates the main thread caused the crash - seemingly related to when an animation is stopped. Can you post the code that handles that?

Comment: I found the Bug. I change the UI at subthread.

Answer (score -1):

Instead try using sleep(1000) for 1sec. Here '1000' represents 1000ms.

Comment: Why do you think sleeping for one millisecond should crash the application?

Comment: Did you mean this cause the crash?

Comment: you answer is not related to question.